# How to read file attributes in a directory?

Tags: python, file

For example:

```
import os
print(os.listdir("path/to/dir"))
```

will list files in a directory.

How do I get the file modification time for all files in the directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When looking for file attributes for all files in a directory, and you are using Python 3.5 or newer, use the [`os.scandir()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) to get a directory listing *with file attributes combined*. This can potentially be more efficient than using `os.listdir()` and then retrieve the file attributes separately:

```
import os

with os.scandir() as dir_entries:
    for entry in dir_entries:
        info = entry.stat()
        print(info.st_mtime)
```

The [`DirEntry.stat()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.stat), when used on Windows, doesn't have to make any additional system calls, the file modification time is already available. The data is cached, so additional `entry.stat()` calls won't make additional system calls.

You can also use the [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) Object Oriented instances to achieve the same:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path('.').iterdir():
    info = path.stat()
    print(info.st_mtime)
```

On earlier Python versions, you can use the [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) call for obtaining file properties like the modification time.

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir():
    info = os.stat(filename)
    print(info.st_mtime)
```

`st_mtime` is a float value on python 2.5 and up, representing seconds since the epoch; use the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) or [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) modules to interpret these for display purposes or similar.

Do note that the value's precision depends on the OS you are using:

> The exact meaning and resolution of the st_atime, st_mtime, and st_ctime attributes depend on the operating system and the file system. For example, on Windows systems using the FAT or FAT32 file systems, st_mtime has 2-second resolution, and st_atime has only 1-day resolution. See your operating system documentation for details.

If all you are doing is get the modification time, then the [`os.path.getmtime`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) method is a handy shortcut; it uses the `os.stat` method under the hood.

Note however, that the `os.stat` call is relatively expensive (file system access), so if you do this on a lot of files, and you need more than one datapoint per file, you are better off using `os.stat` and reuse the information returned rather than using the `os.path` convenience methods where `os.stat` will be called multiple times per file.

Comment: Can `DirEntry.stat()` get the Date Taken from a photo's EXIF data?

Comment: @Stevoisiak: no. `DirEntry` is purely the bookkeeping information the filesystem has about a given file, and does not include information that is embedded in the file itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want the modified time, then `os.path.getmtime(filename)` will get it for you.  If you are using `listdir` with an argument, you'll need to also use `os.path.join`:

```
import os, os.path

for filename in os.listdir(SOME_DIR):
    print os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(SOME_DIR, filename))
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending Martijn Pieters' answer, it's worth noting that `os.scandir` is not recursive, meaning that it does not guarantee up-to-date `DirEntry.stat()` data for files within subdirectories of the requested directory.

If you're looking for a recursive solution, using `os.scandir` can still be an order of magnitude faster than an approach based on `os.walk`. Here is an example that returns the last modified time of a directory, including all nested files and subdirectories, recursively:

```
import os

def get_mtime(path, is_root=True):
    """Returns the last modified time for all files recursively within the `path` directory."""
    mtimes = []

    with os.scandir(path) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.is_dir():
                mtimes.extend(get_mtime(entry.path, is_root=False))
            else:
                mtimes.append(entry.stat().st_mtime)

    return max(mtimes) if is_root else mtimes
```

This can be modified to aggregate relevant data for other particular use-cases.